# Django - Video not played in ios

Tags: django, python-2.7, video, mp4

I'm pretty sure this is a Django issue because if I configure Apache not to use Django to serve the file, it plays fine in my iPad.

If I point to the file directly (no jwplayer, Flash, etc), I just get the play arrow with a slash through it. Like I said, the video plays fine in IOS if it's not being served via Django. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe headers sent. But why are you using Django to serve static files first? It's not recommended.

Comment: I suppose I'm not understanding. I'm writing an application in Django that allows users to play videos.

Comment: I believe @MaximeLorant means it's better to use a separate proxy server to serve your static files rather than the django server itself. Like [nginx and gunicorn](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

Comment: Ah. Yes, actually the media is served on a separate server.